# Getting absolute Path of Directory in Application

Tags: macos, swift, applescript

I have built an application where i am using a script. Now i would like to add these script to my package.

How do i add the script?
What would be my absolute Paths to call this Script from my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add scripts in x-code by clicking on your project settings > Build Phases. To access the script in your project and launch it, import `Foundation` into your swift file and do this:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filenameWithoutType, ofType: "scpt") {
    NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath(path, scriptArguments)
}
```